# In Riot JS, opts values don't render inside HTML tag unless there's a static character(s) with it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, riot.js

I have a simple Riot tag, and I noticed I was getting some HTML tags that were rendering empty, when other HTML tags that contain the same property from `opts` render the value just fine.

```
<sample>
  <p>Full name: { opts.full_name }</p> // <--works
  <p>{ opts.full_name }</p> // <-- renders empty <p></p>
</sample>
```

If I add just a single empty space in the HTML tag with the `opts` property, then it works:

```
<sample>
  <p>{ opts.full_name } </p> // <-- Add a space, and it works
</sample>
```

This appears to only be occurring with `opts`, because when I set a local property as the only contents of an HTML tag, it works:

```
<sample>
  <p>{ foo }</p>
  this.foo = "bar"
</sample>
```

And so does this when I assign a local property to the value of an `opts` one:

```
<sample>
  <p>{ full_name }</p>
  this.full_name = opts.full_name
</sample>
```

I should add that I'm doing this in a Chrome Extension using the `riot.csp.js` with the content script.

Here is my manifest `content_scripts` rule:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "js": ["libs/jquery.js", "libs/underscore.js", "libs/riot.csp.js", "build/tags.js", "content.js"]
    }
```

The pre-compiled tag file:

```
<sample>
  <p>Full name: { opts.full_name }</p>
  <p>{ opts.full_name }</p>
  <p>This is the data: { JSON.stringify(opts, null, 2) }</p>
  <p>{ foo }</p>
  this.foo = "bar"
</sample>
```

The `tags.js` file (compiled):

```
riot.tag2('sample', '<p>Full name: {opts.full_name}</p> <p>{opts.full_name}</p> <p>This is the data: {JSON.stringify(opts, null, 2)}</p> <p>{foo}</p>', '', '', function(opts) {
  this.foo = "bar"
});
```

The `content.js`:

```
$("body).append("<sample></sample>");
riot.mount('*', data);
```

The data object being passed:

```
{ "full_name" : "Homer Simpson" }
```

Altogether, my HTML renders out:

```
<sample>
  <p>Full name: Homer Simpson</p>
  <p></p> <-- troublesome bit: why is this empty?
  <p>This is the data: {
    "full_name": "Homer Simpson"
  }</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</sample>
```

Although I have the above-mentioned workarounds, it's not idea. What is going on?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: what riot.js version are you using? I don't see any problem with current version http://plnkr.co/edit/GXE1pCOgAZdBPGUr1xzP?p=preview

Comment: v3.0.1. I've also gotten this to work in a traditional implementation like you have. So, my belief is the issue is isolated to a Chrome Extension implementation or the `riot.csp.js` version